# How to make sure that a function is called only after an object is build?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback

I have a `common service.js` that has common functionalities but the one which I am using and creating is as below :

```
this.createFastlookupDictionaryForEmployee = function (data) {
        --code to build dictionary
        return dictionaryArr;
    }
    
    this.getEmployeeId = function (dictionaryArr,employeeId) {
        return dictionaryArr[employeeId].
    }
```

**Controller**:

```
function onPageLoad(Callback1,
                Callback2,
                Callback3) {
                myService.getEmloyeeList().success(function (data) {
                    $scope.employeeLookupList = commonService.createFastlookupDictionaryForEmployee(data.items);
                    Callback1();
                    Callback2();
                }).finally(function () {
                });
            }
            
  $scope.getEmployeeId = function () { //callback function 1
                myService.getEmployeeData().success(function (data) {
                    var employeeId = $scope.employeeLookupList[10]; //error here as the $scope.employeeLookupList is not populated yet
                }).finally(function () {
                });
            };
```

All the callback functions are accessing data from `$scope.employeeLookupList` array object. Now the problem is since `getEmloyeeList` API call returns a lot of data and that's why it is taking time to build Dictionary, the callback function calls are completed and hence it is unable to read certain employees ids.

I can't pass the callback to `createFastlookupDictionaryForEmployee` method since it is being used in a lot of places.

How do I make sure the dictionary is created and only after that my `Callback1, Callback2` will be called?

I don't want to call Callback1 and Callback2 before the dictionary is populated.

Answer (score 0):

You should call your `Callback's` the same way you did for your first service `myService.getEmloyeeList()`. That being said, you should wait for the response of it using `success` / `finally` like so:

```
this.createFastlookupDictionaryForEmployee = function (data) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        // code to build dictionary

        // after dictionary been resolved
        defer.resolve(dictionaryArr);

        // if you need to throw an error you can use it like
        // defer.reject("error");

        return defer.promise;
    }

myService.getEmloyeeList().success(function (data) {
 $scope.employeeLookupList = [];
 commonService.createFastlookupDictionaryForEmployee(data.items).then(function (data) {
           $scope.employeeLookupList = data.items; //response from service
           // Do something when request comes with success response
           // I think you should then receive the data on your callback's
           Callback1(data.items);
           Callback2(data.items);
      })['catch'](function (resp) {
         //Do something after error responses
      })['finally'](function () {
         //Do something after success or error responses
      });
}).finally(function () {
});
```

This way `Callback's` functions will only be called on success using the data from request. After this, you could watch for `$scope.employeeLookupList` to check if it is empty or not.
Happy coding :)

Comment: createFastlookupDictionaryForEmployee is not at API call so why do we wrap it up inside ".success" ?

Comment: I am getting error on "commonService.createFastlookupDictionaryForEmployee(data.items).success" saying "It is not a function"

Comment: Like in your example you did used it inside success, you should have an service createFastlookupDictionaryForEmployee(data.items) at your service commonService rigth?
Your request needs to have a http dispatcher so your could user .sucess or finally

Comment: But createFastlookupDictionaryForEmployee(data.items) is a normal javascript function hence it does not have HTTP dispatcher. createFastlookupDictionaryForEmployee(data.items) method is exactly the same which I have posted in my question

Comment: Oh I did undestood now. Check my edit. ['catch] and ['finally'] could vary due angularjs version